# VBA erroneously adds slashes to formatted date

Tags: vba, filepath

A file is created every Friday with the formatting: "Report 08 11 2017.xlsx"

```
Dim iWeekday As Integer, LastFridayDate As Date
iWeekday = Weekday(Now(), vbFriday)

LastFridayDate = Format(Now - (iWeekday - 1), "mm dd yyyy")
```

LastFridayDate is formatted the way it appears in the file path, as '08 11 2017'. However, when i attempt to open the workbook via:

```
Dim lw_report As Workbook

Set lw_report= Workbooks.Open("Report " & LastFridayDate & ".xlsx")
```

I get error: "Report 08\22\2017.xlsx" cannot be found

How can I get the file path created so that the spaces are preserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LastFridayDate` is defined as a date so when you are trying to open the workbook the date is concatenated with standard date formatting.

To fix this simply `dim` LastFridayDate as a String

```
Dim iWeekday As Integer, LastFridayDate As String
iWeekday = Weekday(Now(), vbFriday)

LastFridayDate = Format(Now - (iWeekday - 1), "mm dd yyyy")
Dim lw_report As Workbook

Set lw_report = Workbooks.Open("Report " & LastFridayDate & ".xlsx")
```